# How to use |> and correctly pattern match tuple inputs?

Tags: julia

I have trouble understanding why the below doesn't work?

```
(10, 10) |> ((a,b) -> a + b)
```

The actual use case is alot more complicated, but I am hoping to understand this simple pattern in Julia first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`((a,b) -> a + b)` is a function of two arguments, while the tuple `(10, 10)` is just one value.  Alternatively to splatting, as @Gnimuc proposes, you could unpack the argument in the lambda:

```
julia> (10, 10) |> (((a,b),) -> a + b)
20
```

But I find the extra comma a bit ugly, to be honest.

Comment: I prefer this one as it's shorter and easier to understand than @Gnimuc's

Comment: Removing the outer parens feels much better: `(10, 10) |> ((a,b),) -> a + b`

Answer (score 3):

the pipelining operator only supports single argument chaining:

````
"""
    |>(x, f)

Applies a function to the preceding argument. This allows for easy function chaining.

# Examples
```jldoctest
julia> [1:5;] |> x->x.^2 |> sum |> inv
0.01818181818181818
```
"""
|>(x, f) = f(x)
````

`(10, 10) |> ((a,b) -> a + b)` is equalent to `((a,b) -> a + b)((10, 10))` which is obviously illegal in Julia because it's missing a splatting operator `((a,b) -> a + b)((10, 10)...)` and hence:

```
julia> (10, 10) |> x->((a,b) -> a + b)(x...)
20
```

Comment: oops! it looks like someone that hates `|>` downvoted this answer. :)  Disclaimer: this is neither a common nor good coding pattern in Julia (it makes code hard to read), and I never use it in practice, but maybe it's ok in some specific use cases. In practice, one might prefer to use macros to create a syntax sugar.